# Flagging a Question as off-topic

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I think, it's a feature request, but feel free to re-tag it if necessary.

When you are flagging a question as off-topic, there should be an option:

- Belongs to English Language and Usage

I think, it should be also agreed with ELU moderators to make a matching feature at ELU to quickly migrate questions here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Migration paths are generally not opened until graduation. While exceptions are made from time to time for public betas, they are never opened in private beta, and there are several things to be cautious of here:

- Migration from ELL to EL&U runs the risk of draining ELL of questions. Beta sites tend to have few questions after the honeymoon period of the first few weeks; we don't want ELL to wither and die.
- Migration from EL&U to ELL can cause ELL to become a "dumping ground" for EL&U (a problem experienced with SO and Programmers). We also don't want ELL to be flooded with EL&U questions; rather the site should grow organically (this seems to be contrary to point #1—after all, a site can't be both too big and too small at once—but the right balance is hard to identify in the early days).
- Arbitrary migration can create an unclear distinction between the two sites; this line should be drawn before any migration paths are opened.

Moderators will be able to migrate between the two sites once ELL reaches public beta, and this is generally a sufficient solution for most betas.

Comment: @Choirbean - Yes, and the migration path from ELU to ELL has been opened. As for going the other way around, there's always the "other" reason where you can voice your concern there.

Comment: I guess this is mostly a newbie question, then, and I apologize - I promise I'm not trying to be argumentative! - but just to clarify, I can mark a question as needing to be migrated, but I can't specify *where* I think it ought to go?  Right now, I can only suggest it go to ell.meta.

Comment: @Choirbean As J.R. notes, you should flag it for moderator attention and then suggest the destination in the comment box provided. Moderators have greater discretion for migration targets than community members do. I do not know why the option to migrate ELL to EL&U is not available to the community yet.

Comment: There is no comment box under "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network".  If we *shouldn't* go to that option to suggest that a question belongs to a different site in the Stack Exchange network, then the option shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Choirbean it's not as if there aren't any options on that page... you can say that questions should be moved here, to Meta... that's it because we don't have any sites set up. SE as a whole made the decision that migration should be relatively rare, so we do not allow regular users to recommend migration unless a migration path has been set up. As has been noted, you can always flag a post for moderator attention, explain that you think it should be migrated, and they will consider whether it should be migrated and make that decision.